# Copying a MySQL table from one database to another where table structures differ

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the contents of a table from an old database (`old_db`) to a new one (`new_db`). The `new_db.table1`'s structure is already set but it is empty.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM old_db.table1;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title     | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| criteria  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| threshold | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| code      | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

SHOW COLUMNS FROM new_db.table1;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title     | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| criteria  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| threshold | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| code      | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| parent_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I run:

```
INSERT new_db.table1 SELECT * FROM old_db.table1;
```

I got the following error.

```
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'code' cannot be null
```

I realize that it tries to copy `old_db.parent_id` to `new_db.code` due to column ordering.

I cannot drop the `new_db.table1`:

```
DROP TABLE new_db.table1;
```

because it is connected to another table in `new_db`:

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

A potential solution might be (not tried):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE new_db.table1 MODIFY code varchar(50) NULL;
INSERT new_db.table1 SELECT * FROM old_db.table1;
UPDATE new_db.table1, old_db.table1
  SET new_db.table1.code = old_db.table1.code
  SET new_db.table1.parent_id = old_db.table1.parent_id
  where new_db.table1.id = old_db.table1.id;
ALTER TABLE new_db.table1 MODIFY code varchar(50) NOT NULL;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Is there a method that I can copy a table from another table in another database where table structures are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
INSERT new_db.table1 
SELECT id, title, criteria, threshold, code, parent_id 
FROM old_db.table1;
```

Then the output of **old_db.table1** has the right order for **new_db.table1**

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I got the following error: `ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (``new_db``.``table1``, CONSTRAINT ``table1_parent_id_70dfdfa2_fk_table1_id`` FOREIGN KEY (``parent_id``) REFERENCES ``table1`` (``id``))`. I then removed `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` constrain and it worked.

Comment: I'm marking this correct because it worked in all other cases I have (it was possibly my error in the previous comment.). Thanks.